# Can I debug annotation processor using IntelliJ Idea-community edition?

Tags: intellij-idea, annotations, remote-debugging, kapt

I followed pretty much everything in [this](https://medium.com/@joachim.beckers/debugging-an-annotation-processor-using-intellij-idea-in-2018-cde72758b78a) blog to debug my annotation processor. However, I'm not able to attach the debugger I'm getting the below error.

```
Unable to open debugger port (localhost:5005): java.net.ConnectException "Connection refused (Connection refused)"
```

Is it really possible to debug annotation processer using community edition or does it requires licenced version?

Remote Debug configuration
[image]

Here is my configuration
[image]

I have debug Build process set to on.

Comment: Your link to the blog post is wrong (points to the image). Did you start the build of the project so that JVM for the `jps` is spawned and starts to listen on port 5005? Check that the build process is running and listening on the specified port.

Comment: @CrazyCoder updated it. How to check build process is running and listening on the specified port?

Comment: Run build at least once, the build process will be spawned, assuming you are on Windows, Sysinternals Process Explorer will show it in the [tree](https://i.imgur.com/dtHn0z4.png). `compiler-server` is the [working directory](https://i.imgur.com/xnIFqoZ.png) of this process. TCP/IP properties tab will show [the port it's listening on](https://i.imgur.com/UA2SowA.png). In the status bar you will see [this](https://i.imgur.com/gIb5jIc.png). Make sure you've enabled [this option](https://i.imgur.com/NwySok8.png) via Help | Find Action.